# Getting 400 on Post request with Angular 2 and Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, angular

So I am currently trying to have my Angular2 application send a post request to my Spring backend, but I am continually receiving 400 errors.

Service on Angular2 Front-End:

```
createEntry(name: string, url: string){
  let body = JSON.stringify({sid:null,entryName: name, entryUrl: url, dtcreated:null});
  console.log(body);
  return this.http.post(environment.serviceURL + 'createentry', body, {headers: this.getHeaders()})
      .map(res => {return res.json();});
}
getHeaders(){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return headers;
}
```

Spring Backend:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/createentry", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ListEntry createEntry(@RequestParam(value = "entry") ListEntry entry){
    System.out.println(entry.getEntryName());
    System.out.println(entry.getEntryUrl());
    entry.setDtCreated(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    return listRepository.save(entry);
}
```

The error I'm getting from the console in my browser is:

POST http://localhost:8001/createentry 400 ()

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that it is a pretty simple fix.

I just had to change

`public ListEntry createEntry(@RequestParam(value = "entry") ListEntry entry)`

to

`public ListEntry createEntry(@RequestBody ListEntry entry)`

and it started working right away. Apparently with Spring, @RequestBody is used for all POST and PUT requests while @RequestParams are used for GET requests.